# Fatal error while using ob_get_clear()

Tags: php, fatal-error, output-buffering

I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ob_get_clear() in
>   C:\wamp\www\project1\linking_files.php on line 5

When i use the `$result1 = ob_get_clear();` code to read and store my output in the variable. Can i use anything else in place of  `ob_get_clear()` function?

Comment: You mean `ob_get_clean`?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the function is named `ob_get_clean()`